# Print Plot of String Equation in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and have this pretty simple question.

I am importing an equation from a json file called `run.json`. The JSON looks something like this.

```
    "equations": {
        "spec": {
            "expression": "x*x*x+2*x",
            "seed": 0,
            "range": 100
        }
    }
```

Im loading in the file like so

```
library("rjson")
result <- fromJSON(file = "run.json")

png('plot-spec.png', width=4, height=4, units='in', res=300)
specExpression = result$equations$spec$expression
seed = result$equations$spec$seed
range = result$equations$spec$range

# using noquote to remove quotes from the specExpression as it came in as a string
specEquation = function(x){noquote(specExpression)}
curve(
specEquation,
    from=seed,
    to=range,
    ylab="Y",
    xlab="X")
```

I keep getting the following error  **`'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'`**. Not too sure what to do with it

Comment: I think sharing the contents `specExpression`, `seed` and `range` can help reproduce the problem.

Comment: Those variables are exactly whats being pulled from the json file.  If you create a json file with the equations field shown above, you should be able to replicate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some perusing it looks like using `eval(parse(text=specExpression))` in the actual function creates an entity that can actually be evaluated.

Here is the whole code

```
png('plot-spec.png', width=4, height=4, units='in', res=300)
specExpression <- result$equations$spec$expression
seed <- result$equations$spec$seed
range <- result$equations$spec$range

specEquation <- function(x){eval(parse(text=specExpression))}

curve(
specEquation,
    from=seed,
    to=(seed+range),
    ylab="Y",
    xlab="X")
```